# Gdb with lzma but still has the warning " LZMA support was disabled at compile time"

Tags: c++, gdb, centos7, gdbserver

When I open the dve-full64, it has this following warnings and fail to open.

```
warning: Cannot parse .gnu_debugdata section; LZMA support was disabled at compile time
```

Even when I had install gdb with lzma, this warning still exist.
It is my configuration of gdb.

```
$ gdb --configuration
This GDB was configured as follows:
   configure --host=x86_64-pc-linux-gnu --target=x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
             --with-auto-load-dir=$debugdir:$datadir/auto-load
             --with-auto-load-safe-path=$debugdir:$datadir/auto-load
             --with-expat
             --with-gdb-datadir=/usr/local/share/gdb (relocatable)
             --with-jit-reader-dir=/usr/local/lib/gdb (relocatable)
             --without-libunwind-ia64
             --with-lzma
             --with-python=/usr
             --without-guile
             --with-separate-debug-dir=/usr/local/lib/debug (relocatable)
```

How can I resolve this problem

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43482837/warning-cannot-parse-gnu-debugdata-section-lzma-support-was-disabled-at-compi

Comment: It should not be possible that `gdb --configuration` shows `--with-lzma`, and still get that warning, because they check the same config.h define `HAVE_LIBLZMA`.

Answer (score 0):

> How can I resolve this problem

The fact that you ran `configure --with-lzma` doesn't mean this GDB was built with it (and given the warning, we can be pretty sure it was built *without* LZMA).

You need to examine `config.log` and find out *why* `--with-lzma` didn't have desired effect. Probably `lzma-dev` (or similar) package is missing, and the headers / libraries it provides were not found (or where not usable) at configuration time.